# Locating and/or calling a built-in MATLAB MEX file

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm reading through some MATLAB source code in order to translate MATLAB's `imhist` to Python.  Inside `imhist`, the following call is made:

```
y = imhistc(a, n, isScaled, top);  % Call MEX file to do work.
```

As the comment implies, `imhistc` comes from a MEX file.

I can open and run `imhist` without a problem:

```
EDU>> edit imhist
EDU>> x = [0.1 0.1 0.1; 0.1 0.1 0.1];
EDU>> counts = imhist(x, 64);
```

But when I try to open `imhistc` with `edit imhistc`, I get a prompt that says,

> File /home/daniel/imhistc.m does not exist.  Do you want to create it?

And when I try to run `imhistc`, I get the following error:

```
EDU>> y = imhistc(x, 64, 1, 1);
??? Undefined function or method 'imhistc' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Thus, `imhistc` is available to `imhist`, but unavailable to me.

How can I access `imhistc`?  I'm imagining the answer will apply to built-in MEX files in general.

Comment: Why not use OpenCV for this in Python, e.g., [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_begins/py_histogram_begins.html)?

Comment: @horchler yeah, so i'm building up to that.  my plan is to translate the MATLAB, then compare my translation to `OpenCV` and/or `skimage`.  in general, it seems that there are many tiny differences between the image processing in MATLAB and in those two python options.  (and i need to replicate the MATLAB version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `imhistc`, as the error implies, is a precompiled mex file, so you won't have direct access to its source code.  The reason `which imhistc` doesn't work is that `imhistc` is in a directory named `private` located in the same folder with `imhist`.  You'll note that if you look inside the `private` folder that there is also a `imhistc.m` file in there, but it is only there to return an error message if the mex version of `imhistc` is unavailable for some reason.

That doesn't help you convert the program, but at least it will let you know that you've hit a brick wall regarding following that particular code path.

Comment: ah, bummer.  i did a google search of `imhistc` and found `C` source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/mirone/source/browse/trunk/mex/imhistc.c?r=1874&spec=svn1874), though i'm not sure this is MATLAB-endorsed.  (@horchler)

Comment: There are a number of image histogram functions with full source code on the Matlab file exchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) that may be helpful.  Do a search for `imhist` there and you will hopefully find one that may be helpful to you.

Comment: @horchler is it true that, in general, the MATLAB MEX files are closed-source?

Comment: @dbliss: Looks like decent `mex` code even if it's a bit old. It shouldn't be too hard to get it to compile. All the mex functions I know of are closed, though they may cite references and may be based on Matlab code from earlier versions. It's sometimes possible to extract a version of some code by using Matlab `coder`/`codegen`, but it's not a convenient process. It's also possible that The MathWorks might make certain files available on request, but 'm not sure.

Comment: The mex files used by MATLAB toolboxes are usually precompiled and closed, but sometimes there's an alternate .m file you can use.  Also, if you have the Matlab Coder product, it includes alternative .m files for many functions, although they're intended for conversion to C code.  I note that `imhist` is supported by Coder, with some limitations (http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html).  MATLAB Coder is a pretty specialized product (and pricy), but sometimes it's amazing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're hoping to view the code in `imhistc`, you're out of luck. It is a private `mex` file, but it's *compiled* C code. In R2015a, at least, there is a private  documentation M-file for `imhistc`, but the one line error check in it won't run unless the `mex` file of the same name is missing. In case it's helpful, the help (type `help private/imhistc` or `edit private/imhistc` in your Command Window) indicates

> COUNTS = IMHISTC(A, N, ISSCALED, TOP) computes the N-bin
>   histogram for A. ISSCALED is 1 if we shouldn't compute the
>   256-bin histogram using the values in A as is. TOP gives the
>   maximum bin location.

You can locate the compiled file at

```
[matlabroot '/toolbox/images/images/private/']
```

You can try to view what's in this file, but I don't think that you'll find it very helpful:

```
type([matlabroot '/toolbox/images/images/private/imhistc.' mexext])
```

Comment: i wish i could accept both answers.  in effect, i threw a coin.  (and @Tony needs the rep more than you do.)

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but maybe someone in the future will find this useful. I was recently doing the same thing as you and ran into the same problem.  I found what appears to be an archived version of imhistc on the google code archives. You can find it at

https://code.google.com/p/mirone/source/browse/trunk/mex/imhistc.c?r=1874&spec=svn1874

I coded up a simplified version based on that c code and was able to get the same numbers out, so i think it's probably what's still being used.

Cheers

Comment: yeah, if you look above, i actually posted this link in a comment under the accepted answer.